# Trigger Jupyter Notebook in Azure ML workspace from ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

How do I trigger a notebook in my Azure Machine Learning notebook workspace from Azure Data Factory

I want to run a notebook in my Azure ML workspace when there are changes to my Azure storage account.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that your use case is 100% valid and it is currently possible with the `azureml-sdk`. It requires that you create the following:

1. Create an Azure ML Pipeline. Here's a [great introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-your-first-pipeline).
2. Add a `NotebookRunnerStep` to your pipeline. [Here is a notebook demoing the feature](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/3c9cb89c1ada8626f496d364c3d1b1bdf78bbdb3/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-with-notebook-runner-step.ipynb). I'm not confident that this feature is still being  maintained/supported, but IMHO it's a valid and valuable feature. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1146) to learn more
3. [Create a trigger using Logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-trigger-published-pipeline) to run your pipeline anytime a change in the datastore is detected.

There's certainly a learning curve to Azure ML Pipelines, but I'd argue the payoff is in the flexibility you get in composing steps together and easily scheduling and orchestrating the result.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is currently supported by Azure ML Notebooks. You can also use [Logic apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-trigger-published-pipeline) to trigger a run of your Machine Learning pipeline when there are changes to your Azure storage account.

Comment: what about `NotebookRunnerStep`? [This demo notebook is old](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/3c9cb89c1ada8626f496d364c3d1b1bdf78bbdb3/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-with-notebook-runner-step.ipynb), but it is still part of `azureml-notebook-contrib`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I just confirmed that you can indeed run an AML pipeline from ADF using the notebook runner step. I have updated my response accordingly. Thanks again!